# Sonata element text

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata, symfony-sonata

I'm using Sonata 3.0 for Symfony 3.4.20. Backoffice works well but I don't know why but some text elements of my page are not the good ones. For example there is three actions buttton type

> Show content
>
> Edit content
>
> Remove content

Text butttons are "action_show", "action_edit", "action_delete" instead of "Show", "Edit", "Delete"

[Image result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/binTP.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the Symfony translator is not enabled in framework.yml

Comment: Thank you it was that I added translator: { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] } in config.yml at framework section